# Roof supports moving

Tags: framing, roof, attic, studs, truss

See [these pictures](https://imgur.com/a/oRbCxqE) of a support in the middle of our attic. Taken 6 months apart, last June and now.

Last June, it had already appeared to have moved sideways since installation (house was built 5 years ago) and I was monitoring it for signs of further lateral movement.

Strangely enough, when I checked it again today, it appears to have moved upwards instead.

I also see that another couple roof supports, one on each side of this one, and resting on the same wooden beam, also appear to have moved upwards, with a gap below them too. The one pictured in the middle of the roof moved most, with the biggest gap underneath it. The others were about half that gap size. I believe all 3 were flush with the beam last June.

Really not sure what to do here. Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Note: after some internet searches, I'm beginning to think this is truss uplift because the ceiling of the attic is insulated and any truss uplift could therefore show up in the attic not the floor below. House is in North Texas, so we do get considerable seasonal variation here. Last few winters have been unusually cold.

It might be a concern here even if not structural because of the ac vent and ac refrigerant lines hanging off that particular post.

Comment: Somebody bumping into posts could be the cause. Three similar in a row sounds like a deflection problem, though. Have you considered the beam's deflection? As the beam deflects, the post tracks along the angle of the toe nails as they pull apart. As the beam springs back (with load removal), the toe nails can bend or buckle, allowing the piece to land somewhere other than where it started. With the toe nails pinched in between post and beam, the gap can remain long after the offensive load has been removed. Did you have some heavy material in this neighborhood?

Comment: These posts are in the attic. There's nobody up there bumping into them. There has never been any heavy material stored up there either. I don't thing the beam they're resting on has deflected any or I'd probably see signs of that in the drywall in the floor underneath. Not a single crack there.

Comment: The IRC prescribes a deflection limit of L/240 for ceilings with non-brittle surfacing like gypsum board. For a 10 ft span, that's 120"/240 = 1/2". That's a half inch deflection that wouldn't damage the gypsum board. I suspect that your beam span is longer than 10 ft, and I suspect that your gap is smaller than 1/2".